# Flutter align hint text to center vertically and horizontally in SearchBar Widget when height is less than default

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, searchbar

I am trying to create a search bar in my app which includes a hint text in it. However my output of it looks weird where the hint text is not align to the center vertically on the SearchBar. The img and block below is my output and my code:

[image: img]

```
SearchBar(
  hintText: 'Search Employee',
  hintStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(const TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFA1A5C0), fontSize: 11)),
  constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 28),
  leading: const Icon(Icons.search, size: 15),
  elevation: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(0),
  side: MaterialStateProperty.all(const BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(1, 1, 1, 0.1))),
  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40))),
)
```

Comment: This is happening because of the height of your SeachBar. Flutter developers are currently working on fixing this issue and a fix will be released soon I believe https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/128068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [known bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/127092) and flutter team [fixed this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/128068), but it takes time to merge into stable channel, so you can use `TextField` instead like this:

```
  TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'Search Employee',
      hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFA1A5C0), fontSize: 18),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(1, 1, 1, 0.1)),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
      ),
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(1, 1, 1, 0.1)),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
      ),
      prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search, size: 36),
      prefixIconColor: Colors.black,
      constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 28),
      isDense: true,
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      filled: true,
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use custom control like this one :

```
Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                    border: Border.all(width: 1)),
                child: TextFormField(
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      alignLabelWithHint: true,
                      contentPadding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                      hintText: "Search Employee",
                      hintStyle:
                          TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFA1A5C0), fontSize: 12),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                    )),
              ),
```

Benefits of using something like this are:

1. Fully customisable UI
2. You can add controls as per your requirement

Comment: i tried your way and adjust the ```Container``` to my required height, but the hint text does align to the center. (if the img in the question is align more towards the bottom, after apply your way, the hint text align more towards to the top)